# How to find out a register contains inputs or outputs or both?

Tags: microcontroller, output, input, register

I don't have much experience with embedded systems and I am trying to check if is possible to determine if a register is made of inputs or outputs or a mix of inputs and outputs.

Let's say I have a 32 bit register like so: `"11111111111000000000000000000000"`

Is there a possibility to check if this is made of inputs/outputs/both ?

The project that I work on, already does this somehow when run on hardware, but I need to simulate a method that given a register determines what is made of.

Comment: What? register is a memory element. It has both inputs, to write it and outputs to read it. These are not always accessible to the programmer, but always exist internally.

Comment: I don't have much experience with low level programming, but in  my code there are 32 bits (unsigned), and I have to check if this unsigned value has all bits as inputs or outputs. Is that even possible ?

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of GPIO direction control register? Which MCU is it?

Comment: I don't have this information unfornatelly  and is hard for me to explain this, because of my lack of knowledge, but basically, when I change an output, I need a mask to tell which of the bits from the 32 ones to modify. I don't know if this apply to a specific board or not.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are doing? Do you have any code? Any schematic? Any description? Anything?

Comment: Right now I am at home, so I don't have any code. But for simplicity, when you access  IO from a board in code, how can you tell if its input or output ?

Comment: Repeating yourself doesn't give us more information...

Comment: You know it from knowing the hardware. Open the datasheet and see if the register is RO, WO or RW.

Comment: Of course, I am looking for something programatically....I know from code that they use some masks and do something like: "val1 & val2 &val3" and they determine if the 4 bytes contains only inputs or outputs.

Comment: It's a rare case where you can tell the access direction of an arbitrary register programmatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time Eugene, I guess, I would have to talk with the hardware guys from work for more info.

Comment: If these are GPIO pins of a microcontroller, you the programmer control which pins are inputs and which are outputs. Examine the rest of your program (and the libraries you use) to see which bits are set as inputs and which as outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to find out a register contains inputs or outputs or both?

By reading the register reference manual.

If the only thing you can do is read and write registers, there's no way to tell the difference between the following three cases, all of which are reasonably common:

- a read-only bit that's currently zero
- a bit that's unused and always reads as zero
- a bit that's write-only and reads as zero

Worse, writing the wrong values to some registers may have unwanted, and possibly irreversible, effects on the peripheral.